# maven clover plugin java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com_atlassian_clover.CloverVersionInfo.An_old_version_of_clover_is_on_your_compilation_classpath

Tags: maven-plugin, clover

have somebody faced this issue with open sourced clover plugin for maven?

I'm trying to follow this [instruction](http://openclover.org/doc/manual/4.2.0/maven--basic-usage.html), but once I'm trying to run

```
mvn clean clover:setup test clover:aggregate clover:clover
```

I'm getting this error

```
[CLOVER] FATAL ERROR: Clover could not be initialised because of an unexpected error. 
(class java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com_atlassian_clover.CloverVersionInfo.
An_old_version_of_clover_is_on_your_compilation_classpath___Please_remove__
_Required_version_is___4_1_2()V)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.459 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

*clover-mavan-plugin version: 4.2.1 / 4.2.0, java 1.8*

Answer (score 1):

The message states that there are unexpected Clover version in the runtime. It looks like you have duplicate Clover on your classpath, or other Clover version was used to instrument sources and other one is added in the runtime to classpath.

- Check your pom for Clover dependencies and clover-maven-plugin.
- Make sure you don't mix Atlassian Clover and OpenClover, although one being fork of the other one, you can't simply mix them.

Another explanation is that you duplicated Clover dependency (in different versions) made somehow to your project, but the solution is basically the same.